# How can I unistall Evolution without removing Gnome?

Tags: gnome, evolution

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with the Gnome desktop. When I installed Gnome, it automatically installed Evolution mail client. I'd like to remove Evolution, but when I try to uninstall it through the Software Center, it wants to remove Gnome-core as well.  Is there a way to uninstall Evolution without removing any of the Gnome software?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I would like to describe it more thoroughly, in hopes of finding a more complete answer. I'll link it when I post.

Answer (score 1):

The `gnome-core` package is a meta-package. As Evolution is part of 'GNOME' it includes a dependency on the `evolution` package as well. It is completely safe to remove `gnome-core` as it won't remove all of GNOME (or any of it, as it's a meta-package).

Comment: When I try to remove evolution's packages from synaptic it also wants to remove unity stuff and etc, that's why I'm afraid to delete it