# How to remove Evolution without gutting Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, apt, evolution

Fist of all, I have no idea how all these separate concerns (email, calendar, phone and physical address directory) all got rolled into one program, or why that program was then made a critical component of the desktop system. Evolution is broken for me in a variety of ways (yay large feature sets :/), and I would like to remove it and replace it's features one at a time, as needed, with single-purpose software.

Unfortunately, due to said tight coupling, removing Evolution is sketchy. `apt-get remove evolution-data-server` also wants to remove Unity! Surely, Unity is capable of running without Evolution? I *really* want that server gone, it keeps opening browser windows asking me to authenticate Evolution (The local program instance, or the organization that develops it? Huge difference!)

So, suggestions for solutions? I have an idea, but I'm not sure about some of the details.

1. Generate a .deb file for Unity [using](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592551/how-to-create-a-deb-file-from-installed-package#answer-592553) [dpkg-repack](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/dpkg-repack.1.html)
2. Remove any references to Evolution
3. Replace the current local Unity apt file with the one I just edited, wherever Ubuntu stores the APTs of installed programs. `apt-get` will read those, and not just read some cache somewhere, right?
4. Try again: `apt-get remove evolution*`

Similar questions, that may have helped, but didn't lead to a solution:

- [How can I uninstall Evolution without removing Gnome? (2013!)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266002/how-can-i-unistall-evolution-without-removing-gnome#)
- [Evolution: how to remove calendar of other exchange user without deleting it from the server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851900/evolution-how-to-remove-calendar-of-other-exchange-user-without-deleting-it-fro)
- [How to completely remove evolution including configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710652/how-to-completely-remove-evolution-including-configuration)
- [How to remove evolution-data-server in 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871590/how-to-remove-evolution-data-server-in-16-10)

Comment: The Evolution application itself is not even installed by default in Ubuntu. You can remove it just fine. No, you cannot remove the back-end which many applications use.

Comment: Use for what, though? If I'm not using the features it provides, then those other applications might never notice it missing. Assuming I even use any of those other applications.

Comment: Use for calendar and contacts storage. This is how the time and date indicator in Unity shows upcoming events and such. It's how event reminder notifications work. It is a core part of Unity.

Comment: Are you sure that `apt-get remove evolution-data-server` wants to remove Unity? I seem to remember doing it dozens of times and Unity survived unharmed...

Comment: I only use Unity as a window / desktop manager. I have disabled everything that would communicate over the network, when I am trying to find local files or commands. I do not need it to use those features; if I want them, I will find software that provides them in a simpler manner.

Comment: Yes, `apt-get remove evolution-data-server` wants to remove address-book-service evolution-data-server gnome-contacts libfolks-eds25
  qtcontact5-galera qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony0.1 and our friend *unity8*.

Comment: Oh! Perhaps Unity itself is only a meta package? If that were the case, then removing Unity should leave me with a working Unity. Although it would break as soon as the devs factored out anything important into a new dependency of the Unity meta package.